# lightbox image size restriction

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

I am using this [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/) and I was wanting to know is there away to scale the image to a particular size - I have tried max-height and max-width but they are not setting correctly.

The lightbox is based on the [tractor images](http://www.agrilife.co.nz/products/by_product/57/SAME-Commando-603/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
#lightbox img {
  border: none;
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px; 
}
```

if you want all images to be same size and aspect ratio 16:9

Comment: Thanks,  I have done this but if you go and have a look you can see what its doing

Comment: Try setting `height: auto;` or `height: 100%;`.

Comment: I have tried that - Its the 2nd image thats my issue the first ones fine

Comment: It's JS problem...not accepting css, preloading images and gets real width and height...one solution is crop all images to same size. To be able to help you more I'll must to rewrite the whole script. Try Fancybox.